# Hide /var/spool/mail/{users} to other users

Tags: centos, centos7

I'm new on server configurations. I'm working on CentOS 7.5 with Directadmin. I'm not sure if this is a usual thing but if I `ls -l /var/spool/mail/` from a user account I can see all the other usernames (`admin` included) in that folder.

Is it something normal or should I hide it? Eventually how could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/var/spool/mail/`  ([or `/var/mail` where most UNIX put it](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s11.html)) is normal, leave it alone. Permissions allow only you to read your mail.

(There are more reliable ways to enumerate users, such as `getent passwd`.)